# Java, write data in file and split on multiple lines

Tags: java, format, doubly-linked-list

I have a Doubly Linked List, and in that list I must generate 100 random values. I done that already. Then, I need to store values of Doubly linked list, into a text file. I done that too.
In the end, I have to format my document, to have 5 values on line for example:

TIP: I will write those lines as random values, don't matter order, I used bubblesort to sort them and I reversed them after, but all I need is to know how to put these values like this:

```
1 14 23 4 55 
6 39 91 1 4

etc.
```

I also tried to override toString and I added there "for" and "if", but result was fail. Here is my code:

```
DLL ran = new DLL();  //this is my class named DLL
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        Integer n = new Integer((int) (Math.random()*100));
        ran.startValue(n);      //this is my add function, to add elements in list
        System.out.print(n+" ");
    }

  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));

    out.write(ran.toString());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show your toString method? You are doing a for loop, with an if on the index for modulo 5?

Comment: yes, kind of, this is my toString()
public String toString() 
 {
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
   if(i%5==0)
    return data+"\r\n "+prev;
  }
  return data+" "+prev;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a `get(int i)` function, I would write the `toString` as follows:

```
 public String toString(){
     String ans = ""; 
     for(int i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
          ans += this.get(i) + " ";
          if(i % 5 == 0)
              ans += "\n";
     }
     return ans;
 }
```

This is how you would write a `get(int i)`:

```
public int get(int index){
    Node head = this.head;
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
         head = head.next;
    }
    return head.getData();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Abundance, but I don't have a get(int i) function there. I have only "Node" data types and one "int size;"

Comment: Do you perhaps have a Node next() function or field? Also, how do you access the data value in your node? Is it node.data?

Comment: yes, I have a Node next and prev. And in DLL I have int size; int Node head; int Node end, and node.getData();

Comment: then, the idea is similar but without using a get, you will use next. I will write a different answer.

Comment: there is a little problem, I have 2 x toString()....one in Node class like : return data+" "+next;, and another in DLL class like: return head.toString() . In Node class, I can't write "this.length" , but I can use this.getSize() if I override toString in DLL class. But if I override toString() in DLL class, I can't access getData() anymore

Comment: why can't you access getData in DLL, like node.getData()?

Comment: because getData() in Node class, is type int. public int getData() {return data;}

Comment: So can't you do something like: `Node head = this.head; head.getData();` which will call the getData in the node from the DLL class.

Comment: Yes, it works now ! :D Thank you very very much @Abundance :)

Answer (score 1):

If its just about the formatting just use this.

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    Integer n = new Integer((int) (Math.random()*100));
    ran.startValue(n);      //this is my add function, to add elements in list
    System.out.print(n+" ");

  if(i%5==0)System.out.println("");
}
```

But I agree with @Hovercraft that you should use PrintWriter and it also provides a newline print method by default. No need to override toString() here

Comment: Thank you, and @Hovercraft, I will try with PrintWriter  and temp value for counter

Comment: I updated: no need for temp since you already have variable i

Answer (score 0):

Using your Node and DLL functions provided, you can probably do something like this in your DLL class:

```
public String toString(){  
   String ans = "";  
   Node head = this.head;  
   for(int i = 0; i < this.size; i++){  
        ans += head.getData() + " ";  
        if(i % 5 == 0)  
            ans += "\n";  
        head = head.next;  
   }  
   return ans;  
}
```

This would be equally easy to write in a while loop as follows:

```
public String toString(){  
   String ans = "";  
   Node head = this.head;
   int i = 1;  
   while(head != null){ 
        ans += head.getData() + " ";  
        if(i % 5 == 0)  
            ans += "\n";  
        head = head.next;  
        i++;
   }  
   return ans;  
}
```

Comment: I want to thank you for your effort in solving my problem, this code has no errors, but when I call : out.write(ran.toString()), my numbers from out.txt, are still in the same position, all in a single row.

Comment: my teacher, gave me a hint . he said like this : in DLL class make a function: public DLL GetElementFrom(index i), and call this function using :  for(int i=0;i<ran.getSize();i++)
 out.write(ran.GetElementFrom(i).toString())

Comment: I'm surprised that it still gives the same output, despite the newline character being placed.

Comment: The GetElementFrom(index i) would be equivalent to the get(int i) method that I posted before. I'll update the method to include that.

Comment: Don't work , numbers in txt file are still on same position :( , thank you for your inference !